# How to convert C# to Qt widget code (C++) for namespace and extends class

Tags: c#, c++, qt-creator, qt5.4

I am using Qt 5.4 for my android and iOS.

I have a C# code,but I don't know how to convet it to Qt(C++).

In C#
A.cs

```
namespace WS
{
        public enum myTypes
        {
            T1,
            T2,
            T3,
        };

         public abstract class GS
        {
           protected Color _penColor = Color.White;
           protected bool ReadBaseProperty(BinaryReader reader, string readFileVersion)
            {...
            }
        }...
}
```

B.cs

```
namespace WS
{
    public class sL : GS
    {
        public virtual int PC
        {
            get { return PointList.Count; }
        }...
     }
}
```

In Qt, I try

A.h

```
namespace WS{
   class GS
   {
    public:
    GS();
   }
}
```

the another file:

```
A.cpp

#include "GS.h"
WS::GS::GS(){}
```

the another file:
    B.h

```
namespace WS{
   class sL:public GS
   {
    public:
    sL();
   }
}
```

the another file:
B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
WS::sL::sL(){}
```

Is it a correct format for Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I'll give it a go.

There's no 1-to-1 conversion from C# to C++ However here are the parts that you can convert:

A.cs

```
namespace WorkSystem
{
    enum myTypes
    {
        T1,
        T2,
        T3
    };

    class GS
    {
        protected:
            GS() { }
    };
}
```

GS has a protected constructor to prevent initialization, there's no such thing as abstract in C++

B.cs

```
namespace WorkSystem
{
    class sL : public GS
    {
        public:
            virtual ~sL() { }

            virtual int getPC()
            {
                return 0;
            }
    };
}
```

sL has a so-called [virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Now for the other parts:

- Color:
  This is a System.Drawing structure, which is NOT C++, but C++/CLI.
- BinaryReader:
  This is a class only available in C#. To read from files you have to use stdio or a third party library.
- PC:
  Properties are not available in C++, instead you use functions as getters and setters.
- PointList.Count:
  I'm assuming this is a C# list class. Again these do not exist in C++, but can be replaced by a std::list

Comment: You write A.cs and B.cs? Do you mean A.cpp and B.cpp? If so,what about A.h and B.h? By the way, I thought the namespace should be in .h file...>///<